# Idris: How do I call Idris function from Vala/C and return a string back to C/Vala

Tags: vala, idris

I have this toy 
[project:](https://github.com/bigos/jacekFFI/blob/master/Main.idr)

For the UI I use Vala code that is compiled to C. So I can display a message in UI that comes from Idris.

Both on Idris ans Vala/C side I have this method that sets the pointer to the Idris function. So in Vala code you can see:

`global::afni = fn;`

that sets a global variable with a pointer to Idris the function.
Later in another Vala method I call:

```
    int res = global::afni(0);
    string da_label = @"blah $res";
    Gtk.Label label = new Gtk.Label (da_label);
```

So I call `comFn` function that is found by pointer stored in global::afni, so far so good, it seems to work with integers.

But how do I make it work with strings?

I have tried various ways to change types and return string as an argument and got errors related to invalid pointers

> free(): invalid pointer

and

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vala has the concept of ownership transfer. When a string is returned by a function, Vala assumes that it is responsible for freeing it once it is finished using it. The [Idris FFI](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/ffi.html) looks like it allocates all its data inside the VM and manages it forever.

You probably need to tell Vala the return type is `unowned string` instead of `string`. This will prevent Vala from trying to free it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice works! - https://github.com/bigos/jacekFFI/commit/7495c843ccea6b26ee5591675840c866571f5bcf